# cannot send email with javamail and zimbra server

Tags: java, email, zimbra

I try to send email using javamail to Zimbra server but always receive error **Client host rejected: Access denied**

This is my java code:

```
public class TestMail {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        // provide recipient's email ID
        String to = "other_email@domain.com";

        // provide sender's email ID
        String from = "admin@domain.com";
        // provide username
        final String username = "admin@domain.com";
        // provide password
        final String password = "password-here";

        // provide host address
        String host = "mail.domain.com";
        // configure SMTP server details
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       // setting starttls
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        // create the Session object
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        
        

        try {
            // create a MimeMessage object
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // set From email field
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // set To email field
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

            // set email subject field
            message.setSubject("Here comes Jakarta Mail!");

            // set the content of the email message
            message.setText("Just discovered that Jakarta Mail is fun and easy to use");

            // send the email message
//          Transport.send(message);
            
            Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtp");
            tr.connect(host, username, password);
            message.saveChanges();
            tr.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            tr.close();

            System.out.println("Email Message Sent Successfully");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
    }
}
```

I think error because it seems java code don't send **AUTH PLAIN** but I don't know why, maybe I forget configure properties?

But with nodejs code then email sent success with **AUTH PLAIN**

DEBUG LOG:

```
DEBUG: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.domain.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 mail.domain.com ESMTP Postfix
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.domain.com", port: 587
EHLO Admin
502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
HELO Admin
250-mail.domain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<admin@mitc.vn>
250 mail.domain.com
RCPT TO:<other_email@domain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   other_email@domain.com
DATA
554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 554, with response: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied

RSET
554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2374)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.data(SMTPTransport.java:2080)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1300)
    at test2.TestMail.main(TestMail.java:74)
```

Comment: Can you please provide your full stack trace?

Comment: This may be permission issue from email is not enough permission or not authorized to use authentication. You can check with command line with same details and raise issue to your email configuration team.You can see this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485284/com-sun-mail-smtp-smtpaddressfailedexception-554-5-7-1-cdae-jee-302-01-uci-cu

Comment: @jmizv i updated debug log

Comment: `554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied` this probably means that your mail server is configured to not allow access from your host. Talk to the server admin.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  i think java code don't send AUTH PLAIN so it's not Authenticated